# Ionic Searchbar with PHP API

Tags: ionic-framework

It works but i anot getting the results it should sort. I am getting the same results regardless what i type in the searchbar

I want it to sort like autocomplete. to show results of what i type in the search bar

search.ts

```
  @Component({ selector: "page-search", templateUrl: "search.html" })
  export class SearchPage {
  filter: string = '';
  public userDetails: any;
  public resposeData: any;
  public dataSet: any;
  public userSet: any;
  public mediaSet: any;
  public noRecords: boolean;
   userPostData = {
     uid: "",
     token: "",
     username: "",
     bio: ""
  };
 constructor(
     public common: Common,
     public navCtrl: NavController,
     public app: App,
     public menu: MenuController,
     public authService: AuthService,
     public http: Http,
     platform: Platform,
     statusBar: StatusBar,
     splashScreen: SplashScreen
 ) {
     this.initializeItems();
     this.mostmediaList();
  }
 initializeItems() {
     return this.userPostData;
 }
           getItems(ev: any) {

              this.initializeItems();
              let val = ev.target.value;

              if (val && val.trim() != '') {
                  this.authService.postData(this.userPostData, "userGroupSearch").then(
                      result => {
                          this.resposeData = result;
                          if (this.resposeData.allArtistsData) {
                              this.userSet = this.resposeData.allArtistsData;
                                  console.log(this.userSet);

                          } else {
                              console.log("No access");
                          }
                      },
                  );
              }
          }
```

Comment: You are getting TypeErro, is result response an Array type? can you show us the response format (just log it).

Comment: Post your Authservice postdata function code so can get idea what type of data your returning from this function.

Comment: if `this.resposeData` is an array.. then there wont be `this.resposeData.items`... your code doesnt make sense do you mean `this.resposeData.items.filter()`?

Comment: Now i am getitng No access

Comment: I am getting results but does not return the results i want. It doesnt sort well. Regardless of what i type it returns the same results. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is wrapped into

```
if (this.resposeData.items) {
    //some code
}
```

we know for sure that `this.resposeData` is not an array, since it has an `items` member (otherwise your code inside the `if` would not be executed and hence you would not get an error as in the case we have).

Since you call the parameter `items` at

```
this.userSet = this.resposeData.filter((items) => {
    //some code
};
```

it is safe to assume that you wanted to `filter` `this.resposeData.items` instead of `this.resposeData`. So, you will need to make sure it is an array at the `if`

```
if (this.resposeData.items && Array.isArray(this.resposeData.items)) {
    //some code
}
```

and `filter` `this.resposeData.items` instead of `this.resposeData`:

```
this.userSet = this.resposeData.items.filter((items) => {
    //some code
};
```

Comment: sorry resposeData is an array

Comment: @SimosIoannidis If you console.log(Array.isArray(resposeData)); what do you get?

Comment: I am getting the same array regardless of what i type

Comment: @SimosIoannidis have you tried whether it is an array in the console as I have described in my previous comment?